# Getting video frames from a video in Android

Tags: android, image, video, android-camera

I'm writing an app that captures a video from the camera of the Android device. I'm trying to get all the frames of a video without repeating frames and store them in some kind of list. By "without repeating frames", I mean this:

If I call `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time, OPTION)`, there is a chance that two calls to this method can return the same frame if `time` hasn't changed much. I want to increment `time` enough before the next call to `getFrameAtTime()` such that I don't get the same frame again.

Obviously, I also want to make sure I don't miss any frames.

One way to do this is to get the frames per second of the video and increment `time` by the frequency of frame capture. But how would I get the frames per second of the video I captured?

Or how else would I accomplish this?

Comment: Care to explain why its off-topic? I can make appropriate changes.

Comment: Where is the camera involved? (it's not a reason to close,  it's simply not clear from your description)

Comment: BTW, I believe that the 'java' tag is not relevant.

Comment: The video was captured using the Android camera. I thought it might interest those interested in camera, and they might have the know how to answer this. Java tag removed. Thanks.

Comment: why not capture frames directly from Camera?

Comment: This way, I'm using the default camera feature and don't have to code my own camera functionality. I just need to create a new intent and I can get the video.

Comment: @Cricketer you got solution for above your question? i want to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can register a [PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) handler. This interface declares onPreviewCallback() method which is called exactly as you want: once for every distinct video frame. The parameter is the raw camera image.

Comment: Can I use this even if I'm not writing my own camera functionality? I'm just using a MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent to allow the user to record a video and when my activity gets back the focus, the recorded video is handed to my app through Intent data.

Comment: No, you can't. But you can launch the recorder in parallel.